# Updates from a large number of tables

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I want to fill a table with millions of rows with a lot of updates (about 600).

I have created a table "all_combinations..." with the ID (appln_id) and the corresponding columns where the default values are 'FALSE'.
Next, I have tried to update the columns from about 600 tables. Whenever the ID from "all_combinations" correspond with the ID in one of the tables, the respective column is set to 'TRUE'.
The 600 table names correspond to the 600 columns I want to fill, e.g. 'A01C':
If A01C can be joined with all_combinations, the column A01C should be set to TRUE.
I have been running this code for about 3 days.
Any ideas how to speed things up / to improve the code?

```
create table all_combinations_ipc4_compr (
appln_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
a01b BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01c BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01d BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01f BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01g BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01h BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01j BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01k BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01l BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01m BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01n BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
a01p BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
... 600 variables

insert into all_combinations_ipc4_compr
select distinct appln_id from other_table;
-- millions of IDs!

update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01b=TRUE from a01b t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01c=TRUE from a01c t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01d=TRUE from a01d t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01f=TRUE from a01f t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01g=TRUE from a01g t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01h=TRUE from a01h t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01j=TRUE from a01j t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01k=TRUE from a01k t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01l=TRUE from a01l t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01m=TRUE from a01m t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01n=TRUE from a01n t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a01p=TRUE from a01p t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
update all_combinations_ipc4_compr t1 set a21b=TRUE from a21b t2  where t1.appln_id=t2.appln_id;
... 600 updates
```

Comment: Tables have _columns_ not "variables" - but this looks like a really bad data model

Comment: `CREATE TABLE xxx AS ... 599 FULL OUTER JOIN`s, plus a`COALESCE(...600 terms)` would probably be uglier. ...

Comment: suggestions how to improve the data model?